# SSL session is at layer 3 or layer 4

Tags: tls

An SSL session is established between two nodes (via ip addresses,layer 3) or between applications ( layer 4) ?
Thanks

Comment: Neither layer 4 or 3. Its on layer 5 or 6 or 7. Depending on the application.

Comment: Let's suppose i want to connect to a server encrypting both skype and a browser with SSL (for example) do i need 2 sessions ?

Answer (score 1):

IP, and TCP/IP pre-dates the OSI model. Layers 1-4 of OSI *almost* map to the network and TCP/IP stack (which TLS sits on top of) but if you keep trying to explain one in terms of the other you're going to become lost; there are at least 3 session layers in a HTTP/2 application (TCP, TLS, HTTP), usually 4 (+application state) and sometimes more (+authentication).